# tailwindcss/vue: generated css file doesn't include custom classes from <style> section

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindcss with mode:jit and vue, I use this command to create my styles

> "tailwind": "NODE_ENV=production postcss ./src/assets/index.css -o ./dist/index.css"

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">Some text</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.hello{
  @apply text-9xl text-pink-600
}
</style>
```

this is the result

```css
.text-9xl {
  font-size: 8rem;
  line-height: 1
}
.text-pink-900 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgba(131, 24, 67, var(--tw-text-opacity))
}
```

but how I can get a result like this?

```css
.hello {    
    font-size: 8rem;
    line-height: 1;    
    --tw-text-opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(131, 24, 67, var(--tw-text-opacity))
}
```

**Update:**
If I build the whole project then ".hello" is placed in my bundled js

[image]

So it should be possible, but I don't know how to generate a separated css file like that..

**Update2**

I have created a small repo, maybe this helps to solve my problem.
https://github.com/gregorvoinov/tailwind

Answer (score 0):

Works in Vue 3 when I did

**`tailwind.config.js`**

```
ringColor: (theme) => ({
      DEFAULT: theme('colors.blue.500', '#2156C9'),
      ...theme('colors'),
      focus_border: '#2156C9',
    }),
```

**tailwind.css**

```
focus:ring-focus_border
```